# How to create inner join with 3 table

Tags: php

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM main_table;
+--------+----------+--------+
| id_book | id_author      |description |
+--------+----------+--------+
| 1           | 101     |   I love cat |
+--------+----------+--------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM author;
+---------+-----------+
|  id_author | name_author |
+---------+-----------+
| 101     | Dr Sent     |
+---------+-----------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM book;
+--------+---------+
| id_book | name_book |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |     cat |
+--------+---------+
```

hello I am still new in PHP now im bit confuse with PHP and MySQL. I have a drop drown list which is related to one of my table in database.

firstly my system appear a page of list author's name and user will able to choose which one user like.

```
 JK ROWLING 
 DR SEUSS <-- author_name
 ROAD DAHL
```

Next, it will go to a new page and have a select(list/menu) which show a list of BOOK NAME. 
I can retrieve the dropdown list from database, but my problem is when I select one of BOOK NAME in the dropdown, it show all book description and cannot select the right description.

here is my coding to make it more clear

```
$currentPage = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

mysql_select_db($database_config, $config);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM book ORDER BY name_book ASC";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $config) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

$maxRows_Recordset2 = 1;
$pageNum_Recordset2 = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_Recordset2'])) {
  $pageNum_Recordset2 = $_GET['pageNum_Recordset2'];
}
$startRow_Recordset2 = $pageNum_Recordset2 * $maxRows_Recordset2;

$colname_Recordset2 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['id_book'])) {
  $colname_Recordset2 = $_GET['id_book'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_config, $config);
$query_Recordset2 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE id_book = %s ORDER BY description ASC", GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset2, "int"));
$query_limit_Recordset2 = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_Recordset2, $startRow_Recordset2, $maxRows_Recordset2);
$Recordset2 = mysql_query($query_limit_Recordset2, $config) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_Recordset2'])) {
  $totalRows_Recordset2 = $_GET['totalRows_Recordset2'];
} else {
  $all_Recordset2 = mysql_query($query_Recordset2);
  $totalRows_Recordset2 = mysql_num_rows($all_Recordset2);
}
$totalPages_Recordset2 = ceil($totalRows_Recordset2/$maxRows_Recordset2)-1;

$queryString_Recordset2 = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  $newParams = array();
  foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (stristr($param, "pageNum_Recordset2") == false && 
        stristr($param, "totalRows_Recordset2") == false) {
      array_push($newParams, $param);
    }
  }
  if (count($newParams) != 0) {
    $queryString_Recordset2 = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
  }
}
$queryString_Recordset2 = sprintf("&totalRows_Recordset2=%d%s", $totalRows_Recordset2, $queryString_Recordset2);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha im sorry because im new in here..thank you for ur advice

Comment: If want help with your PHP code as well you could post "sprintf" results too for a better understand.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha what do you mean by no longer maintained and are officially deprecated? is that mean this mysql_* is outdated?

Comment: @confusingOne: Yes, that's exactly what it means. *Severely* outdated. **Horribly** outdated even.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha *No number* ***of font-styles*** **can** accurately ***depict how outdated*** *they* in fact **are**.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.........

```
SELECT 
    a.*, b.*, c.* 
FROM main_table a 
    inner join author b on a.id_author = b.id_author 
    inner join book c on a.id_book = c.id_book
```

Comment: seriously I dont know this version is outdated.but just asking is what other statement you guys use ? and its still okay if im continue using this my_sql_* ?? how about recordset? is it suitable using this?

Comment: Read the links in the comment I left you in the comment on the question. The alternatives are listed there.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd recommend using [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_php.asp) and staying on the same page when an item is selected. By this you can separate the code for the different input boxes and it'll look better at the end of the day.

To answer your question, here's the SQL Statement for mySQL you should run to get what you asked for:

```
SELECT MAT.*,AUT.name_author, BOO.name_book
FROM main_table AS MAT, author AS AUT, book AS BOO
WHERE (MAT.id_book=BOO.id_book AND MAT.id_author=AUT.id_author) AND MAT.id_author=101
ORDER BY MAT.id_author, MAT.id_book;
```

You can find the SQL Fiddle code for the above guy [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50cb6/4). *You can update the "filtering" in the `WHERE` clause to filter by another table's author ID or by book ID*

Comment: okay thanks to all of you for helping me and my friends..ive got the answer right now :) but only join 2 table. it is more easy because name of the author is few :)